# Event Extraction from Recurrence Pattern

Tags: python

I've been working on a event based AJAX application that stores recurring events in the a table in the following format (Django models):

```
event_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=24)
# start_date - the start date of the first event in a series
start_date = models.DateTimeField()
# the end date of the last event in a series
end_date = models.DateTimeField()
# Length of the occurence
event_length = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
rec_type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

The rec_type stores data in the following format:

```
[type]_[count]_[day]_[count2]_[days]#[extra]

type - the type of repeation: 'day','week','month','year'.
count - the interval between events in the “type” units.
day and count2 - define a day of a month ( first Monday, third Friday, etc ).
days - the comma-separated list of affected week days.
extra - the extra info that can be used to change presentation of recurring details.
```

For example:

```
day_3___ - each three days
month _2___ - each two month
month_1_1_2_ - second Monday of each month
week_2___1,5 - Monday and Friday of each second week
```

This works fine, and allows many events to be transmitted concisely, but I now have the requirement to extract all events that occur during a given range. For example on a specific date, week or month and I am a bit lost as to how best to approach.

In particular, I am stuck with how to check if an event with a given recurrence pattern is eligible to be in the results.

What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd store an rrule object from python-dateutil (http://labix.org/python-dateutil) rather than inventing your own recurrence format. Then you can just define some methods that use `rrule. between(after, before)` to generate instances of your event object for a given range.

One catch though, dateutil's rrule object *doesn't pickle correctly*, so you should define your own mechanism of serialising the object to the database. I've generally gone with a JSON representation of the keyword arguments for instantiating the rrule. The annoying edge case is that if you want to store stuff like '2nd Monday of the month', you have to do additional work with MO(2), because the value it returns isn't useful. It's hard to explain, but you'll see the problem when you try it.

I'm not aware of any efficient way to find all eligible events within a range though, you'll have to load in all the Event models that potentially overlap with the range. So you'll always be loading in potentially more data than you'll eventually use. Just make sure relatively smart about it to reduce the burden. Short of someone adding recurrence handling to databases themselves, I'm not aware of any way to improve this.

Comment: The format is dictated by a library I am using. Perhaps, I can do some conversion between this and rrule.

Comment: Hm, well that only affects one part of the problem anyway. The key thing you need is a way to generate a list of events between two date ranges, and there's still no efficient way to do this at the database level (that I'm aware of)